# PHP ORM with NOSQL and RDBMS support

Tags: php, orm, nosql, rdbms

Are there any PHP ORM projects which supports MySQL and NoSQL databases such as MongoDB?

I am currently using RedBean to do MySQL ORM, however I woud like to introduce MongoDB to the applicatoin and perhaps even replace some of the MySQL with MongoDB in the future.

An ORM that can allow me to easily transition between both would be nice. However, I tend to not like ORM that requires too much configuration (i.e. YAML, XML etc). RedBean is very nice in that it allows one to easily get things working without too much configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects) supports various RDBMS and NoSQL storages as well

Comment: Are there any other ORM frameworks besides Doctrine? I looked at doctrine before, but didn't really like the fact it it requires loads of configuration.

Comment: @phpdev: I don't know any. Btw, the less configuration ORM requires - the more work it performs in runtime, thus - the slower it becomes.

Comment: @zerkms this is not true. RedBeanPHP builds your schema on-the-fly in fluid mode. When in frozen mode (production) it uses the schema configurations generated using reflections in the fluid phase. This means it's both easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Docrine 2 contains both an ORM and ODM for NoSQL databases (MongoDB and CouchDB are supported), and its theoretically possible to hook up Doctrine to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

We're working on some adapter-based ORM called [UniMapper](http://unimapper.github.io) in our company.

It provides a uniform API for accessing stuff from different kinds of databases, protocols, and 3rd party APIs. You can even associate between entities from different storages. And it should be even faster than Doctrine. Try it give us some feedback :-).

MongoDB will be supported very soon, but you can write extension on your own, it's very easy.

However the quick start is not complete, you can ask me or somebody from our team.

Comment: This is a 2011 question

Comment: @dan :-) so people who find this question should not know about this in 2014?