# Should i migrate to msqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The error below appears when testing in localhost, will mysql still work or should I migrate to msqli?

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\connect.php on line 3

Comment: Migrate directly to PDO

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: have a lok at Doctrine 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770133/php-orm-with-nosql-and-rdbms-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Because of you are using php 5.5 and above versions. Refer this.
[Deprecated: mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect)